How to define query method in spring data jpa if one of the query parameters is fixed?
If I have a customer table with columns cus_no, is_valid and create_time where cus_no corresponds to cusNo attribute (with data type String) of customer object, is_valid corresponds to isValid attribute (with data type of String) of customer object and create_time corresponds to createTime (with data time Date) of customer object.
I defined following method in customer repository class.
@Query("select c from Customer c where c.cusNo = :cusNo and c.isValid = 'Y' order by c.createTime desc")
public List<Customer> getCustomerList(String cusNo);
There are only two values, "Y" and "N", for is_valid column. If I want cusNo being the sole parameter of the method, can the above method be transformed to a query method? I asked Poe and it gave me following query method.
Public List<Customer> findByCusNoAndIsValidOrderByCreateTimeDesc(String cusNo);
However, I'm doubtful whether filtering criteria of isValid = "Y" can be applied to the method.

This question is similar to: Is there any way to use constant (EnumType Ordinal) value in @Query annotation in JPA repository?, Spring DATA JPA how to write a method which use contant value for a field to fetch data and How to use fixed values in Spring CrudRepository?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

190303458 No, you can not create a query method with a fixed parameter like this. However, you can create a more generic query method. It would be Public List<Customer> findByCusNoAndIsValidIsOrderByCreateTimeDesc(String cusNo, String isValid);
You will need to enter 'Y' in the second arguement when calling the query method.
